# change method is not getting called after error in service Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, debouncing

I have a simple search method with RXJS debounce

like this .

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(this._debounceDelay, this._scheduler)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .filter(this.filterForBlank.bind(this))
      .filter(this.filterForLength.bind(this))
      .switchMap(term => this.searchService.serchBy(term))
      .subscribe((data) => {
       // do something
      }, (err) => {
           // show error on UI
      });




private filterForLength(term: string) {
    return (term.trim().length > 2);
  }

  private filterForBlank(term: string) {
    if (isEmpty(term)) {
                return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

but if there is an error, for example, I changed the URL to the wrong one... this change function is not hitting again. even after changing the value

I think I need to kill observable if there is an error. But Exactly don't how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is almost right. If you let the observable error without catching the error it probably won't work anymore. What you need to do is use the catch operator to catch errors and handle it to fail without 'killing' the observable.

This could look like this:

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(this._debounceDelay, this._scheduler)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter(this.filterForBlank.bind(this))
  .filter(this.filterForLength.bind(this))
  .switchMap(term => this.searchService.serchBy(term))
  .catch(errors => {
     return Rx.Observable.empty();
  });
  .subscribe((data) => {
   // do something
  });
```

Now, if you're backend call fails, it will be gracefully handled by the catch clause and will return a new empty value. You could use this empty value to clear whatever data it is you're showing when it succeeds. If it works, it will just skip the catch clause.

EDIT:
You're correct. This will not work. Due to the fact that, if an observable chain errors, the entire chain is broken. To fix it, you need to do this:

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(this._debounceDelay, this._scheduler)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter(this.filterForBlank.bind(this))
  .filter(this.filterForLength.bind(this))
  .switchMap(term => 
               this.searchService.serchBy(term)
                   .catch(errors => {
                            // show error on ui
                            return Rx.Observable.empty()
                   }))
  .subscribe((data) => {
   // do something
  });
```

By Moving the catch statement inside the switchMap, it will be the observable chain inside that switchMap that will break. The original chain however, starting from the 'this.searchTerm.valueChanges' will not break and be kept alive.

My apologies for the wrong answer.

Comment: not working !! it going to catch but after value change again it's not calling API